# How to make rsync delete files/folders on backup server that no longer exist on main server?

Tags: rsync

I am using this command to backup a main server to a backup server.

```
rsync -avz --delete-after --exclude-from '/usr/order/exclude.txt' --password-file=/usr/prod/masterpass.rsync /usr/order/ order@slave::order >> /usr/prod/$log 2>&1
```

I hadn't realised until now that this leaves files/folders on the backup server that are no longer present on the main server.

How do I get it to make it so the backup server is an exact match to the main server i.e. delete files/folders on the backup server that no longer exist on the main server?

Comment: are the "extra" files ones that are contained in the exclude.txt file? If so, there's a --delete-excluded which "also delete excluded files from dest dirs"

Comment: This should erase files from the backup, given the `--delete-after` option. Please make a [small example that we can reproduce to illustrate the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).